# WPF Range Slider not binding

Tags: wpf, binding, rangeslider

I seem to have this same problem with any implementation of a `RangeSlider` (or more simply, a slider with 2 thumbs).

I want to bind both thumbs to a datacontext and have that binding be 2-way.
Unfortunately, I only seem to be able to bind to SET the sliders' positions. If I move them with the mouse they lose their binding.

I have used several range sliders, but to keep it simple, in this example I'm using one from [thejoyofcode.com](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Creating_a_Range_Slider_in_WPF_and_other_cool_tips_and_tricks_for_UserControls_.aspx). (I haven't modified it, so I'm not including it here just now, but I can if it helps).
I consume it using the XAML below, with the intention of letting the framework sliders (named "MinSlider" and "MaxSlider") also be bound to the same datasources.

When I move the framework sliders, all of the bound items follow them, including the range slider, but then if I move one of the thumbs on the range slider it does *not* update the datasource or the framework slider.

My Window XAML...

```
        <Separator></Separator>

        <controls:RangeSlider x:Name="Slider" 
                              Minimum="10"
                              Maximum="20"
                              LowerValue="{Binding Min, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              UpperValue="{Binding Max, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LowerValue, ElementName=Slider}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpperValue, ElementName=Slider}"/>

        <Separator></Separator>

        <Slider x:Name="MaxSlider" Minimum="10" Maximum="20" Value="{Binding Max}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=MaxSlider}"/>

        <Separator></Separator>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Min}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Max}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

...and the MySource class...

```
public class MySource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _min;
    public double Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set
        {
            _min = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Min");
        }
    }

    private double _max;
    public double Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set
        {
            _max = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Max");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: If you change Min and Max in the codebehind, does the slider's position change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you need to set the `BindingMode=TwoWay` in your `Binding`s.

A `Control` author can make this the default behavior (the WPF `Slider` does this), but unless the dependency property is registered with `FrameworkPropertyMetadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault`, then `OneWay` is the mode that will be used.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx) explains `BindingMode`s.